# Jenkins Continuous Integration and Google Glass Project

Tags: git, ant, jenkins, continuous-integration, google-glass

Recently, I have begun the process of developing an application for use on Google Glass. Since I am working with a development team, we are using a Git repository in order to control the versions of our code. Lately, I came across the concept of using continuous integration to test our builds so that potential bugs could be detected and eliminated throughout the course of our development.

Since I have not seen anything particular to setting up Jenkins for Glassware, I would like to know if anyone out there has ever used Jenkins in conjunction with their own repository for Glassware, and I would also like to know how you went about configuring Jenkins.